# How to find a item is publishing or unpublishing in com.tridion.storage.si4t extension

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, si4t

We are using SDL Web 8.5 with DXA Java 2.0. While publishing/unpublishing any item, we are adding that item in Elastic indexer. Is there any way we can find the item is publishing or unpublishing in `com.tridion.storage.si4t` extension?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible. I have done this [SI4T-elasticsearch](https://github.com/avmgan/SI4T-elasticsearch) deployer storage extension based on SI4T framework to publish and unpublish actions to push and remove the items in the elasticsearch index and did present in the TDS, refer to this [article](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/feed/posts/tds-event-presentation-si4t-based-elasticsearch-integration-for-sdl-tridion-web-8-with-dxa-2-0).

I hope it helps